# Is there a way to build an easy related posts app in django

Tags: django

It seems to by my nightmare for the last 4 weeks,

I can't come up with a solution for a "related posts" app in django/python in which it takes the users input and comes out with a related post that matches closely with the original input. I've tried using like statements but it seems that they are not sensitive enough.

Such as which i need typos to also be taken into consideration.

is there a library that could save me from all my pain and suffering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I suppose there are a few different ways to normalize the user input to produce desirable results (although I'm not sure to what extent libraries exist for them).  One of the easiest ways to get related posts would be to compare the tags present on that post (granted your posts have tags).  If you wanted to go another route, I would take the following steps: remove [stop words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words) from the subject, use some kind of [stemmer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) on the remainder, and finally treat the remaining words as "tags" to compare with other posts.  For the sake of efficiency, it would probably be a good idea to run these steps in a batch process on all of your current posts and store off the resulting "tags."  As far as typos, I'm sure there are a multitude of spelling corrector libraries exist (I found [this one](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) after a few seconds with Google).